# How effective were early modern hand grenades?

Tags: warfare, weapons, early-modern, renaissance

I saw a video about the 1683 siege of Vienna, and in the video, it talked about hand grenades that were used in the siege, and that the Ottomans used glass grenades that would explode once shattered and the Austrians would use iron grenades that exploded with a fuse.

That kind of has me going down a rabbit hole of wondering how close you would have to land one of these grenades near someone to kill or injure them to the point where they can no longer fight. I have not been able to find much info on this though. The best I've been able to find was a Wikipedia page about grenades and grenadiers. I quote the grenadier page:

> "...small iron spheres filled with gunpowder ... grenadiers had to be tall and strong enough to hurl these heavy objects far enough so as not to harm themselves..."

They were obviously too heavy to be thrown as far as modern grenades, but surely were talking about a pretty decent blast radius to have "you might not throw it far enough" to be an issue with them. I would also imagine a tennis ball hunk of metal with gunpowder in it would throw out some horrifying shrapnel.

But none of this mentions the glass grenades the Ottomans used (or ceramic grenades that would probably work the same way). They wouldn't have the same shrapnel as the metal bombs, and I would assume a much smaller blast radius (and were probably lighter). From what I know, gunpowder won't really explode like modern high explosives unless there's either a ton of it or its able to be contained and allowed to build pressure when it burns like in iron bombs, so I don't even know how these explosives would work and how they wouldn't just shatter on impact and just leave a pile of gunpowder that dramatically burns but doesn't really create a dangerous explosion.

So how effective were these grenades (both glass/ceramic or metal) in terms of blast radius and lethality? Id imagines the metal ones would be comparable to modern grenades, even if heavier and with less range, but the glass or ceramic ones that break on impact... Surely grenadiers using these would basically have to nearly hit the people they're targeting with these grenades to actually be effective.

Comment: Are you referring to the 1529 or the 1683 siege? Also, please note that both of these dates are usually considered to fall within the early modern period.

Comment: The 1683 siege, I have added the early modern tag to the question. 


Though the grenades used in the siege were specific examples I mentioned, I'm not exactly looking for how effective those grenades were specifically, more how effective the types of grenades used were. I imagine both iron and glass grenades have a history far longer than that specific siege, and I was wondering how effective these kinds of grenades have been historically.

Comment: Re "They were obviously too heavy to be thrown as far as modern grenades": A source considerably later than the Middle Ages states the following. Lewis Lochée, *Elements of Field Fortifications,* London 1783, [p. 22](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Elements_of_Field_Fortification/KvpBAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA22&printsec=frontcover): "The distance at which hand-grenades can be thrown is from 25 to 30 yards."

Comment: This *may* be of interest (I don't have access): Pavlos Triantafyllidis, "War in Medieval Mytilene, Lesbos, Greece: Glass Grenades of the 14th and 15th Centuries", *Journal of Glass Studies*, Vol. 58 (2016), pp. 296-300

Comment: [Museum artifact](https://onlinesammlung.freiburg.de/en/object/Granate%20-%20Gl%C3%A4serne-Handgranaten/EFE01B65438364349427198104033B7D): "[Image] The first reports of powder-filled glass balls date from the occupation of Vienna by the Turks in 1683. They had a particularly horrific splinter effect. [...] Dating: ca. 1740 - 1744 [...] Dimensions: Calibre 10.0 cm, Calibre 12.0 cm"

Comment: Huh. I did actually see this in my initial research but didnt see the "see more" section. 
So glass grenades do create shrapnel. I didnt think they would, I thought the glass wouldve been pulverized into dust by the explosion. Interesting.

Comment: @Chuck I've edited your question to focus on early modern grenades as the question may get closed for being too broad if you cover ancient and medieval periods as well (which is what I think you mean by 'historically'.  You can, of course, change it back if my edit is really not what you want.

Comment: That is for the best. I know (Wikipedia knows) there were early grenades in the byzantine empire that used Greek fire, as well as grenades in China in like 900AD which is a bit too far back for what I'm looking for here. So I appreciate the edit (:

Comment: @Chuck the degree of shrapnelling is dependent on the [brisance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brisance) of the explosive - it's not always proportional to the overall power of explosion. As you correctly noted, black powder "burns violently" rather than detonate, so it creates a relatively slow shockwave, and thus has low brisance. So in comparison to, say, TNT, it would make relatively large, but slow shrapnel.

Comment: @Chuck please move all the comments into the question.  Generally when people see long strings of comments they conclude that the OP is more interested in discussion than answers, and that it will take too long to understand.  (they're usually right).  All the information needed for research should be in the question, not in a long dialogue below the question.

Comment: "Effectiveness" is relative. Even in modern times, blast radius is not everything, because you need to take the tactical purpose of the grenade into account (offensive, like the German Stielhandgranate, or defensive, like the Eihandgranate).

Comment: In this case I'm only interested in the damage it can do.

Comment: @Chuck Again, relative. What damage at what range? Is a 10m blast radius at a range of 2m better than a 2m blast radius at a range of 10m? What about having a barrel of gunpowder and blowing it up? Range zero, but good blast radius. Raw tables of numbers don't answer real questions...

Comment: We're ignoring projectile range here. How far they could be thrown was answered in an earlier comment, about 25-30 yards. All I want to know now is how close would someone have to land one of these grenades to an enemy to kill or incapacitate that enemy.